# jQuery: how to write the double slash '//' so that it does not throw error?

Tags: jquery, double, slash

I have this code:

```
(options.parent) ? top = options.parent.height / 2; : top = parent.height() / 2;
```

Because of the double slash that i use there it get's an error i know why i get the error i just don't know how to write it to work.
Thanks again.

Comment: What double-slash? Maybe my eyes are failing me.

Comment: This code, even fixed, doesn't look that something I'd like to have in my source. It's not the most readable one. Please use if/else or simply `top = condition ? value 1 : value 2;`

Comment: @TonyDay, yes, it's not double slash, it's the semicolon in the middle.

Comment: How did you manage to run your code? When you try to run it is gives you an error in the console: `SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression`, which should have indicated the issue.

Comment: Voting to close as too localised due to typo in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the "double slashes", remove the semicolon

```
(options.parent) ? top = options.parent.height / 2 
                 :top = parent.height() / 2;
```

Semicolon was meant to define end of statement(optional), the ternary operator is treated as a single statement.

```
(options.parent) ? top = options.parent.height / 2; : top = parent.height() / 2;
//                                                ^------ Wrong!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the slash problem but the semicolon. Try this:

```
top = (options.parent ? options.parent.height : parent.height()) / 2;
```